# The verb "Address" here

Tags: word-choice

I am currently reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/finance/news/companies-business-groups-respond-to-president-trumps-china-demands-191247638.html) and I found a line,

> “The Administration’s objective should continue to focus on real structural reforms in China that **address** unfair trade and investment practices

Personally this is a bit hard for me to understand, am I OK to swap this word with these synonyms such as "focus on", "devote theirselves on", sort of words like those?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Administration’s objective should continue to focus on real structural reforms in China that *address* unfair trade and investment practices.

**The Administration’s objective should continue to focus on real structural reforms in China that *DEAL WITH* unfair trade and investment practices.**

---

> **address** verb [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/address) [ T ] (DEAL WITH) to give attention to or deal with a matter or problem:
>
> The issue of funding has yet to be addressed.

---

Link added for future use. [How to use a Dictionary](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-a-Dictionary)